# DD does not work in the nested foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, dd

I am trying to see whats in the variable. It is a multiple nested foreach. Up to a certain point in the foreach it is able to output the dd. Then suddenly it does'nt work anymore, it seems as if Laravel is reading over it.

I have tried with var_dump and that is not working either. If I type random words it does throw error on them, so the code does get there.

The code:

```
foreach ($houses as $house) {
        foreach ($house['forms'] as $form) {
            echo 'Hello World';
            foreach ($projectForms['forms'] as $addedForm) {
                dd($form); //This is the dump I would like to see
                if($addedForm['id'] === $form['id']) {
                    array_push($addedForm['streets'], $house['fullStreet']);
                } else {
                    array_push($projectForms['forms'], array('id' => $form['id'], 'name' => $form['name'], 'percentage' => $form['percentage'], 'streets' => $house['fullStreet']));

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

dd $houses:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 97641
    "fullStreet" => "SomeStreet 1"
    "forms" => array:1 [▼
      0 => array:3 [▼
        "id" => 2456
        "name" => "Some Name"
        "percentage" => 6.6666666666667
      ]
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 97642
    "fullStreet" => "SomeStreet 2"
    "forms" => array:1 [▼
      0 => array:3 [▼
        "id" => 2456
        "name" => "Some Name"
        "percentage" => 6.6666666666667
      ]
    ]
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 97643
    "fullStreet" => "SomeStreet 3"
    "forms" => array:1 [▼
      0 => array:3 [▼
        "id" => 2456
        "name" => "Some Name"
        "percentage" => 6.6666666666667
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

dd $form:

```
array:3 [▼
    "id" => 2456
    "name" => "Some Name"
    "percentage" => 6.6666666666667
]
```

dd $projectForms:

```
array:2 [▼
  "projectName" => "Some Project Name"
  "forms" => []
]
```

I am wondering why the dd is not working in the foreach for the $projectForms. Under the echo above it, it does work.

Comment: `$projectForms['forms']` is __empty__, `foreach` does not run.

Comment: Check what is in `$projectForms['forms']` seem that it is empty

Comment: You are both right. I just realized I should probably add an if statement to check if $projectForms['forms] is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check first data exist in array like: `!empty()`

```
foreach ($houses as $house) {
    if(!empty($house['forms']){
        foreach ($house['forms'] as $form) {
            if(!empty($projectForms['forms']){
                foreach ($projectForms['forms'] as $addedForm) {
                    dd($form); //This is the dump I would like to see
                    if($addedForm['id'] === $form['id']) {
                        array_push($addedForm['streets'], $house['fullStreet']);
                    } else {
                        array_push($projectForms['forms'], array('id' => $form['id'], 'name' => $form['name'], 'percentage' => $form['percentage'], 'streets' => $house['fullStreet']));

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```